# using bitset container in c++

Tags: c++

I have a string of 8 char long that contain

8 bytes the hex dump is

is 801000000000000

It means bit 1 and 12 is on.

How can I use bitset feature in c++ and make my life easy.

Thanks

Comment: What's the question? I don't see no `?` in there.

Comment: @karlphillip ..any  ? * in there.

Answer (score 7):

To do what?  Where's the question?  I can't really give a good example of "how it will make your life easier" without a problem to solve.  All I can do is show you the very basics of how the class works in application.

Here's a link on its [interface](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/).  If you want to handle just a simple, constant size set of bits then you can make one easily.  If you want one that can grow or shrink look to [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html).  Here's a quick example with the standard bitset:

```
std::bitset<40> imFiveBytesLong;

imFiveBytesLong.set(0, true);
```

Now it looks like

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000001
```

with the 0th bit set.  And you can test to see if the bit is set by asking:

```
bool isItSet = imFiveBytesLong.test(0);
```

Or you can count the number of set bits by asking:

```
std::size_t numSet = imFiveBytesLong.count();
```

**Edit**:

To answer your comment below check out the [to_ulong](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/to_ulong/) method of bitset and one of the [constructors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/bitset/) of bitset. Putting it together:

```
int main ()
{
  std::bitset<10> mySet(120ul);          // initialize from unsigned long

  std::cout << mySet.to_uLong();         // print as an unsigned long

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How I can make my string perfectly unsigned long and initialize from unsigned long ?